# Fetching a value from a result?

Tags: node.js, api, botframework, discord, discord.js

So I am fetching values from *chuck norris api*. I am able to fetch and present values when given one value such as when using `random` event from the api. My question is, how can I present a value given to me when there is more than one value displayed in a list?

```
let topic = args.join(" "); //defines topic set as varliable to use in query search

fetch(`https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/search?query=${topic}`).then(result => result.json());
const { sub } = await fetch(`https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/search?query=${topic}`).then(result => result.json());

if(topic !== " ") { return message.channel.send(sub)};
```

Comment: Are you asking how you can do multiple API calls if there are more than one args?

Comment: Yes. If I got a result list that had 5 values to choose. I would like to pick at random and display the value it choosed? Now Im starting think I'm not making any sense lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're asking how to pick one item at random from an Array. [`Math.random`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) gives you a random number between 0 and 1. How can you convert this to a random index in an Array? Multiply by the size of your Array first, then round down with [`Math.floor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor):

```
const response = await fetch(`https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/search?query=${topic}`);
const jokes = await response.json();
const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * jokes.length);
const randomJoke = jokes[randomIndex];
return message.channel.send(randomJoke)
```

Comment: Ah, thank you. It never occurred to me that I would need to use Math.random but me wanting a random output makes more sense now.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to choose a random value from an array of items is to do the following:

```
const randomItem = allItems[Math.floor(Math.random() * allItems.length)];
```